# Twitter Fabric Keep user logged in when phone is restarted

Tags: android, session, twitter, authentication, twitter-fabric

Im creating an Android application that requires a user to log in to Twitter. Problem is when I restart the phone the user has to log in to Twitter again :( ...Im using Twitter Fabric api...Has anyone come across this problem before. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;

public class CDOActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "xxx";
private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "xxx";
private TwitterLoginButton loginButton;
private static TwitterSession twitterSession;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
    LoginHandler loginHandler = new LoginHandler();

    if (hasHeaders()) {
        loginButton = new TwitterLoginButton(this);
        loginButton.setCallback(loginHandler);
        setListFooter(loginButton);
    }
}

public class LoginHandler extends Callback<TwitterSession> {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
        TwitterSession session = result.data;
        final TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient(session);
        new TweetService(twitterApiClient, getApplicationContext());
        twitterSession = session;
        loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException e) {
        Log.i("Problem...","An error was logged from {@code LoginHandler}");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue. Actually mine was getting logged out whenever I was closing the app.

I used `SessionManager` to check whether there is any active session of the application or not. If it's not, am redirecting it to login otherwise am doing the next set of actions under that i.e am calling the function inside that `if..else` condition. I checked it twice. It's automatically getting logged in even after I restart the phone(that was your main issue).

**Sample code:**

```
TwitterSession twitterSession = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
        if(twitterSession!=null)
        {
            getTwitterData(twitterSession); //Custom function in which am fetching the user's profile data
            loginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome Back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Use it inside `onCreate` method.

Hope that helps.

Thanks.